# python if list is equal to reverse decending list

Tags: python

I am trying to check if is sorted = ascending so if yes then it shoudl return True if not it should return False. But now I would like to check if the list is descending, then it should return 'Descending sorted' and I am trying it with the reverse of a list but I get every time the return True so that is sorted although the list is descending sorted and sometimes if I change a few lines and want to print out the list.reverse() I get None. So now I don't how to fix that

Thats where I am now:

```
xs = []
ys = xs.reverse()
def is_sorted(xs):

    if xs == sorted(xs):
        print(True)
    elif(xs.reverse() == xs):       #problem 
        print('Descending sorted')  #problem

    else:
        print(False)
#is_sorted([1,2,3,4,5,6])
#is_sorted([7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
```

Please don't give me a new Code I would like to fix it with my own code and don't wnat to get a new one :)

**Edit**

```
xs = []
ys = sorted(xs)
zx = xs.reverse()
def is_sorted(xs):

    if xs == sorted(xs):
        print(1)
    elif(ys == xs):
        print(-1)

    else:
        print(0)
 #is_sorted([1,2,3,4,5,6])
 #is_sorted([7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
```

I update it but if I use the descending list I get 0

Comment: `xs.reverse()` returns `None` and `xs` is reversed **in place**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so you mean if I return xs after xs.reverse() it should return the rverse of xs?

Comment: @Kate yes exactly. If you print `xs`, then `reverse`, then `xs` again you will notice that it is now reversed.

Comment: @Cyber ok now I update it but doesn't work

Comment: @Kate I advise you to ask a new question

Comment: @MartijnPieters my Problem is not that it don't  returns the reverse, the Problem is I think  the code pass the elif and I already tired it with elif( list(reversed(xs)) == ys):

Comment: @frostnational why I would ask the same

Comment: @Kate because this question is closed and it would take 5 different people to vote to reopen it. I've voted, but it's unlikely to happen. Plus it won't be *the same*, since your code changed a lot.

Comment: @frostnational :( so I have to thnik about a new Titel

Comment: @MartijnPieters so youre teh reason why the question is closed!!
the problem is not the reverse I add comments to my code where the problem is

Comment: @Kate his decision to mark this question as a dupe *was* 100% appropriate. The subject of a question has changed, so the question may be reopened. It's not permanently closed.

Comment: @Kate The answer to your question is `if (xs == xs[::-1])`

Comment: @Kate: your edit makes the same mistake *still*. The dupe shows you how to produce a reversed copy.