# Python Sorted elements in descending order with reverse

Tags: python, sorting

I have the function `is_sorted` that should check if the given list is sorted with the first if else statement:

1. if List is sorted it should return True
2. else return false because it is unsorted (or descending)

Code:

```
xs = []
ys = sorted(xs)
zx = list(reversed(xs))
def is_sorted(xs):

    if xs == sorted(xs):
        print(True)
    elif(list(reversed(xs)) == ys):
        print(-1)

    else:
        print(False)
#is_sorted([1,2,3,4,5,6])
#is_sorted([7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
```

and now I want to add a second if statement that should check if the list is descending so if yes it should print out -1 . I have a problem that I think **the code skips** the elif statement, so if I enter a descending list it print out false. I know that it maybe could be possible to make it with bubblesort but I have created that code now and want to fix it to learn python clearly.

So I stuck at the elif statement

**Edit**

```
def is_sorted(xs):
    ys = sorted(xs)
    zx = list(reversed(xs))

    if xs == sorted(xs):
        return(1)
    if( zx == ys):
        return(-1)

    else:
        return(0)
is_sorted([7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
```

Comment: Why do you sort and reverse `xs` outside the function? Why is `xs` empty? Why, despite your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723082/python-if-list-is-equal-to-reverse-decending-list), are you still assigning the `None` return from `list.reverse()` to a name?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because they tell me I should ask a new question because the question is closed :(

Comment: Note that `zx`  is always `None`, since `list.reverse` returns nothing.

Comment: @Kate the question was closed as a duplicate - did you not bother to read the duplicate and its answers? Also, be clearer about the output of the function - having it `return` either a `bool` or an `int` seems odd.

Comment: @Kate **read the duplicate** this time. `list.reverse()` is *in-place*, so you actually reverse the input `xs` and assign `zx = None`.

Comment: @Kate good. You can simplify - you currently produce `sorted(xs)` twice!